# How to avoid sub entity curly braces in JSON response?

Tags: java, json

I have a java POJO I want the response be in a certain format

I have the code something like below

```
   public class LocationInfo {

     private String locationId;
     private String locationName;

     private State state;
   }
```

This is how I get the response

```
  "localCompanies": {
    "locationId": "345",
    "locationName": "test_location",
    "stateInfo": {
       "city": "test_city",
       "county": "test_county
   }
 }
```

What I really need is

```
  "localCompanies": {
     "locationId": "345",
     "locationName": "test_location",
     "city": "test_city",
     "county": "test_county
  }
```

How to achieve this? thanks in advance.

Comment: The state info needs to be Strings inside of LocationInfo instead of a state object.

Comment: Sedrick, I want State to be a sub entity in that not as a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Jackson` has introduced `JsonUnwrapped` annotation in 1.9.0. All you need to add annotation on target object.

```
public class LocationInfo {

  private String locationId;
  private String locationName;

  @JsonUnwrapped
  private State state;
}
```